# How to implement lit-html instead of juicy-html in a polymer 3 component?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-html

I am converting an app from polymer 1 to polymer 3.  I used juicy-html, but they have not updated to Polymer 3 and I see that there is lit-html.  I am wondering how I can change this snippet to using lit-html.  It is used for expanding a string like: `'Hello <span class="highlight">world</span>!'`

Here is the snippet of code from my polymer 1 component.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.snippets]]">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[item.matches]]">
    <div><template is="juicy-html" content$="[[item.text]]"></template></div>
  </template>
</template>
```

Do I need to implement a new component for the inner div?  Is there an example that I can look at?

Here is the resulting Polymer 3 element to display a highlighted text within a string:

import {html, LitElement} from '@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js';

```
/**
 * `search-snippet-highlight`
 * 
 *
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 * @demo demo/index.html
 */
class SearchSnippetHighlight extends LitElement {

  static get properties() {
    return {
      snippet: { type: String }
    };
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <style>.highlight { background-color: yellow; }</style>
      <div .innerHTML="${this.sanitizeHtml(this.snippet)}"></div>`;
  }

  sanitizeHtml(input) {
    return input; // TODO: actually sanitize input with sanitize-html library
  }

}

window.customElements.define('search-snippet-highlight', SearchSnippetHighlight);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of that `<template>` with `juicy-html` in Polymer's [`LitElement`](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element) (the recommended base element that uses `lit-html`) is:

```
render() {
  let content = '';
  for (const s of this.item.snippets) {
    for (const m of s.matches) {
      content += `<div>${m.text}</div>`;
    }
  }
  return html`<div .innerHTML="${this.sanitizeHtml(content)}"></div>`;
}
```

The `render` function above does the following:

1. builds an HTML string from inputs
2. sanitizes the HTML
3. puts the result into the container `div`'s [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), using `LitElement` syntax (`.PROPERTY="VALUE"`)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Polyfills only needed for Firefox and Edge. -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs@latest/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Works only on browsers that support Javascript modules like
       Chrome, Safari, Firefox 60, Edge 17 -->
  <script type="module">
    import {LitElement, html} from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module';

    class MyElement extends LitElement {

      static get properties() {
        return {
          item: { type: Object }
        }
      }

      constructor() {
        super();
        this.item = {
          snippets: [
            {
              matches: [
                {text: 'hello <span class="highlight">world</span>'},
                {text: 'we are the <span class="highlight">world</span>'},
                {text: 'war of the <span class="highlight">world</span>s'},
              ]
            },
            {
              matches: [
                {text: 'the <span class="highlight">cat</span> in the hat'},
                {text: '<span class="highlight">cat</span>fish are in the water'},
                {text: '<span class="highlight">cat</span>erpillars become butterflies'},
              ]
            },
          ]
        };
      }

      render() {
        let content = '';
        for (const s of this.item.snippets) {
          for (const m of s.matches) {
            content += `<div>${m.text}</div>`;
          }
        }
        return html`
          <style>.highlight { background: rgb(255, 251, 222); }</style>
          <div .innerHTML="${this.sanitizeHtml(content)}"></div>`;
      }

      sanitizeHtml(input) {
        return input; // TODO: actually sanitize input with sanitize-html library
      }
    }

    customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
  </script>
  
  <my-element mood="great"></my-element>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Tony!  That helped me and now I have a search snippet element to show the text matching the query text.

Comment: @LorenCahlander No problem :)

Comment: Why is render not returning ```

Comment: Why is render not returning
 ```
html`<div>${this.sanitizeHtml(content}}</div>`
```
or better still
```
html`<div>${this.item.snippets.map(s => s.matches.map(m => html`<div>${this.sanitizeHtml(m.text)}</div>`))}<div>`
```
Previous comment couldn't be edited. This one the back ticks get confused with stackoverflows own editor

Comment: @akc42 It might be a good idea to ask that as a new question, where proper formatting could help clarify the problem, allowing for others to provide answers you might find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I put this in an answer as @tony19 was suggesting it can be formatted properly.  I wasn't really asking a separate question, really just asking a rhetorical one rather than offering a separate solution.

You can simplify the approach quite a bit as lit allows you to build up your html in layers through the `map` function.

```
render() {    
    return html`
        <div>${this.item.snippets.map(s => s.matches.map(m => 
                html`<div>${this.sanitizeHtml(m.text)}</div>`
            ))}
       </div>
    `; 
}
```

Now one issue with this (and the accepted answer) is that every render you recalculate the whole thing, including sanitizing the Html.  `lit-html` has a `guard` directive that can help with this.  Adding this will provide for it only re-rendering on a change.

```
render() {    
    return html`
        <div>${guard(this.item.snippets, () => this.item.snippets.map(s => 
                 guard(s.matches, () => s.matches.map(m => 
                html`<div>${this.sanitizeHtml(m.text)}</div>`
            ))))}
       </div>
    `; 
}
```

This does require you impose some discipline on how both `this.item.snippets` and the underlying `matches` get updated.  You have to ensure that the "Array" references being used change when there is an update. Something like this (assuming the matches are being updated with a new match) and `sindex` is the index of the `snippet` you want to update and `mindex` is the index of the `match` within that `snippet` you are updating with `newMatch`;

```
this.items.snippets = this.items.snippets.map((snippet, index) => index === sindex ?
   {...snippet, matches: snippet.matches.map((match, index) => index === mindex ?
      newMatch : match)} : snippet);
```